# How can I import a .txt file in R to be read?

Tags: r

I want to know how can I import a .txt file in R, but avoiding pathing to my file. I usually import like this: "Import Dataset" and the a select "From text(base)", but when I write in the program file.exists("myfilename.txt") it tells me FALSE. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Are you sure your file is in your working directory ? Otherwise some precisions would help

Answer (score 2):

When you run `file.exists("myfilename.txt")`, R will search your current working directory for a file called `myfilename.txt`. If you have a file called `myfilename.txt` that you imported from some other directory, then `file.exists("myfilename.txt")` will return `FALSE`.

Solution 1:

- Put your R script and the `myfilename.txt` file in the same folder
- Change your working directory to that folder, either using the session menu or using `setwd("path/to/folder")`
- `file.exists("myfilename.txt")` should now return `TRUE`
- You can read your table with `read.delim("myfilename.txt")`

Solution 2:

- Create an Rstudio project
- Place your R script and the `myfilename.txt` file in the project folder.
- Every time you open the project, your working directory will point to the project folder.
- `file.exists("myfilename.txt")` is `TRUE`
- You can read your table using `read.delim("myfilename.txt")`.

Solution 3:

- Leave `myfilename.txt` where it is and read it by providing the absolute path, for example: `read.delim("C:/Users/Jiakai/Documents/myfilename.txt")`
- In this case `file.exists("myfilename.txt")` is `FALSE` and `file.exists("C:/Users/Jiakai/Documents/myfilename.txt")` is `TRUE`.
- If you want `file.exists("myfilename.txt")` to return `TRUE` change your working directory to `"C:/Users/Jiakai/Documents/myfilename.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

To import a `txt` file, you have several options. The two best options are

```r
readr::read_delim("path/tomyfile/myfilename.txt", delim = "\t")
```

or

```r
data.table::fread("path/tomyfile/myfilename.txt", sep = "\t")
```

They are preferrable to the base `R` `read.delim` function that is slower.

You can provide absolute paths or relative path, if you know your working directory

## Edit

If you don't know your working directory, you can run

```r
getwd()
```

If you don't find your file with `file.exists` it means you need to change your working directory or change the path in your import and `file.exists` command

Comment: I did not get it. I edited the answer about that and will ask precision. Thanks !